# Reordering of matrix in c++

Tags: c++, matrix

I have a matrix in C++, A(n,n) and a vector P(n) which looks something like this:

```
  P = [ 3 6 1 13 12 16 ... ]
```

it contains numbers 1:n but not in an ascending order but scrambled.

My aim is to change the rows and columns of matrix A to the same order. For example since P[0] = 3 I want the 3rd row and 3rd column to move to the 1st row and column in matrix A.

But because the matrix could be potentially really large, I can't use another matrix of size same as A because that would be wasteful.

In matlab this can be done simply by using the command:

```
 A(P,P);
```

Any ideas on how to do the same thing in c++?

Comment: "Since P[1] is 3" - pay attention, C++ starts at 0.

Comment: Changed it. By force of habit I used matlab indexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest using a level of indirection, to locate each matrix in a cell.

Let's say your matrix object is called `M`. Instead of using

```
M[R][C]
```

to refer to the cell in row `R`, column `C` (assuming row-major matrix ordering), you will have an associated pair of vectors, let's call them `y` and `x`, so the value of the cell in row `R` column `C` is:

```
M[y[R]][x[C]]
```

Initially, both `y` and `x` vectors map each "logical" row or column to the corresponding physical row and column, that is both `y` and `x` contain [0..max_row] and [0..max_col].

Then, to effect the swapping in your question, you simply copy your `P` vector to the `y` and `x` vectors.

You should implement your matrix not directly, as a two-dimensional  `std::vector`, but as a standalone class:

```
class Matrix {

public:

// ...

    auto operator()(size_t R, size_t C) const;

    auto &operator()(size_t R, size_t C);

// ...
};
```

and implement the indirect mapping of rows and columns as part of the class implementation.

Comment: Can the indirect mapping be done without using a supplementary matrix?

Comment: Who said anything about a supplementary matrix? Only two vectors. That information has to be stored somewhere. It's fundamental.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly how to implement it. After I copy P to y and x how do I use it on my matrix?

Comment: As I've explained in my answer, to retrieve the value in row R, column C, you access M[y[R], x[C]], instead of M[R,C].

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is probably to just brute-force it. The best idea is probably to do it row by row. You'll need a helper array of length N which keeps track of the original row index, and one temporary row. Then, starting at row R=0, check if row R is in the right position. If not, copy it to the temporary row, copy the right row to row R (permuting it on the go), and copy the temporary row to the spot that was just freed. If a row happens to be in the right spot, copy it to the temporary row, and permute it when copying back.

Comment: And then do the same for the columns? Wouldn't it be almost the same as using a second matrix?

Comment: @System: No, you don't need to do anything for the columns - you permute each row when it's moved to the right location. And no, this uses just a single extra row. But it's of course not as efficient as a second matrix. The algorithm can be optimized by not immediately copying back the temporary row. This means you won't be working in row order. Instead, you copy row 0 to the temporary row, some row N to row 0, and then find the row that should go to row N. Usually, this is some other row M, in which case the process continues, but keep in mind it could also be the temporary row.

Comment: thank you, I think I will be able to do this. Why is it not as efficient as a second matrix?

Comment: @System: On average 2*N row writes.